# Mocha HTML link relative path ../../ doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, mocha.js, filepath

I'm testing my code via mocha on an HTML page and I need to access a node_modules folder which is two folders up from my current directory.

this is the directory structure:

```
-main folder
   -client
      -test
         testPage.html 
   -node_modules
```

On testPage.html I used two links to access the **mocha files** in node_modules:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../node_modules/mocha/mocha.css">
<script src="../../node_modules/mocha/mocha.js"></script>
```

However, the css isn't shown on the page and dev tools says it fails to load the resource (404)

That doesn't make sense, Since I put `../../` as there should be put in order to climb two folders up the current directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I ran the file on VS code console all along. I tried running it on chrome and it worked.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've tested as your folder structure and worked here. Take a look at 
[this repo](https://github.com/sitepoint-editors/mocha-unit-testing)

Comment: On server side I'm using node-js.  Are you certain that it's impossible to climb up two folders? Why?  Should I simply move my HTML file two folders up?

Comment: In testrunner.html the links to node_modules don't include "../../" in the beginning of the link, They are in the same folder as node_modules. This works for me. But what I'm asking is how to get it working when testrunner.html is in "test" folder  which is inside "client" folder as I depicted upwards on my question.

Comment: Yes, ../../node_modules worked for me locally at linux firefox browser

Comment: Worked here at chrome also see the [screenshot](https://pasteboard.co/GAr950e.png)

Comment: As far as I understood: your directory at repo is: -node_modules , -testrunner.html. My directory is -node_modules, - client\test\testrunner.html. These are not the same directories and the latter doesn't demand the "../../" path at the beginning of these two link tags. Can you please post your repo working with the first directory structure I posted? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take look at the address bar on the screenshot at previous comment. I've tested as per your directory structure.

Comment: Okay. Can you share the testrunner.html? I need to see the code you typed that made the reference to node_modules work. All you did was adding ".../../" to these two links just as I did there?

Comment: Here is the [html](https://gist.github.com/newmizanur/04151baabd4f32384a049ea7d76e061f)